# Javascript trigonometry-related expression gives me an unexpected result

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I have this expression:

```
(0.8733 * (Math.atan((0.375 ^ 1.75) * -2.1855))) + 1)
```

and the result I expect is `0.673183`. Wolfram alpha gets it right when I copy+paste the equation into there (replacing Math.atan with arctan)

```
(0.8733 * (arctan((0.375 ^ 1.75) * -2.1855))) + 1)
```

But Javascript gives me this result:

```
0.002977558258926538
```

It's been a while since math class, but I believe there are different ways of expressing the result, so maybe I am getting one out ot Javascript when I expect the other? Or maybe something else is wrong, but I am not sure how to debug this.

What do I need to do differently to get the expected result? Ultimately I want to replace two of these numbers (0.375 and 1.75) with variables to get results along this line of [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xpamxeotod) but due to this unexpected result my expression is not mimicking the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `^`-Operator in Javascript, which is not the power (which is `Math.pow`) but the binary `XOR`-Operator. I think this is not what you intended. Try

```
(0.8733 * (Math.atan(Math.pow(0.375, 1.75) * -2.1855))) + 1)
```

Comment: Surprised that it wouldn't yield `NaN` for trying to xor two doubles :)

Comment: Quite right! Thank you. I updated the title of this question to better reflect the actual problem, for posterity.

Comment: @Jack: In javascript numbers are converted to (32-bit) integers when applied to bitwise operators.